# How are tag badge votes counted?

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-badges, tag-score

I was just looking through my "[tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967315/flem?tab=tags)" progress on my profile and noticed some of the numbers don't add up. Take for example the [[asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:967315%20%5Basp.net-mvc%5D)] tag. It says I have a score of 21 over 25 questions. When I drill down into the questions, I have a score of 22 for answers and 9 for questions. Where did 21 come from?

Similarly, for [[javascript]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:967315%20%5Bjavascript%5D) it says I have 98 votes but I can count 107.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag scores aren't updated dynamically, they're recalculated (I believe) once per day.

The 21 is the answer score you had yesterday for [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). You have one answer today with one upvote. The score should be 22 in a few hours. (Looks about the same for Javascript, I'm guessing you got a couple of upvotes today for answers that date back a bit.)

Question score and wiki posts don't count towards tag specialist badges.